# Is 'UR' an abbreviation or a name?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, synonyms, abbreviations

[image: Text]

Is the word 'UR' here a name or an abbreviation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Write out the sentence you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"UR" is the "short name" of one of the parties to the contract. At the beginning of the contract there is probably verbiage similar to:

> This contract is made by and between Uniform Resources, Inc. (hereinafter "UR") and A-One Consulting Corp. (hereinafter "CONSULTANT").

So it is an abbreviated name.